# How do conditionals in lookaround groups work in .NET regex?

Tags: c#, regex, theory

Playing around with regular expressions, especially the balanced matching of the .NET flavor, I came to a point where I realized that I do not understand the inner workings of the engine as good as I thought I did. I'd appriciate any input on why my patterns behave the way they do! But fist...

**Disclaimer:** This question is purely theoretical, and any result obtained here will never be used, or modified and used in production code to parse HTML. Ever. I promise. I do fear the pony. =)

Now to my problem. I'll try to match the letter `A`, if it is not preceeded by an `#`. To demonstrate, I'll alway use the string `..A..#..A..`. Here, the first `A` should be matched. Of course, this is a quite easy task by using `"A(?<!^.*#.*)"`, but I wish to use conditionals here, since they can be used for balanced matchings and other cool things.

What I tried is

```
"A(?<=^(#(?<q>)|[^#])*(?(q)(?!)))"
```

The way I interpret it is: when the engine encounteres an "A", it goes back to the start of the string, and for every character add an empty match to the capturing group q if the character is a #. Then it should fail if q contains a match. What I don't understand is why this expression matches both As in my sample string.

When I simply remove the lookbehind and match the whole string, this works:

```
"^(#(?<q>)|[^#])*(?(q)(?!))A"
```

matches the whole string up to the first A, even if the first group's quantifier is greedy. Inserting a '#' at the beginning will also cause the match to fail (as desired).

So: how do look around groups, named capturing groups within them and conditionals play together?

Thanks!

**Edit:** This problem can be seen more easily in `(?<=(?<q>)(?(q)(?!))).`, which should not match any character, but matches everything.

Comment: +1 and I only got to second paragraph so far. / Okay, read the whole thing, but too bad this is very C#-specific and I can't contribute... YET! Question favorited and bookmarked!

Answer (score 3):

Conditionals aren't really that useful in balanced matching--or anywhere else, for that matter. ;)  Balanced matching works by using a named capture group as a stack; every time that group matches something, the matched text is pushed onto the stack.  There's also special syntax for popping the stack.  Here's a good introduction:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups

Comment: I actually faced this problem when trying to use balanced matching first. This technique does seem to fail when used in a lookbehind, and I have no clue why. This question is the simplest case where the same failure could be seen.